# Move installed game to external SD Card

Tags: storage, games, sd-card

I have Nokia Lumia 720 with Windows 10. I've limited space left in my phone memory. Is it possible to move the game app and its game data(Asphalt 8 Airborne & Six Guns by Gameloft) to external SD card?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Go to Storage sense.
2. Select internal memory.
3. Click on the game you want to move.
4. Click move button.
5. Select SD card in the drop down list and press move.

This will move the selected game to SD card.

Comment: That moves already installed games to SD card or the game I'll install in future?

Comment: well, in storage sense, just mark sd card as apps installation path, so all apps/games will install in sd itself in future.

Comment: But I said move the games to SD card and not install the games

Comment: exactly, you can do that in storage sense, just open it and explore